# Какую ОЗУ добавить к серверу материнка X8DT3?

Tags: сервер, железо

есть сервер супермикро с материнкой X8DT3 , у него уже стоит 4 планки по 4гб NT4GC72B4NA1NL-CG , нашел вроде описание

https://nson.org/komplektuyushhie/materinskie-platy/supermicro-x8dt3.html

но не совсем понимаю "поддержка памяти-до 96 Гб 1333/1066/800 МГц DDR3 ECC регистровой, до 24 Гб 1333/1066/800 МГц DDR3 ECC небуферизованной;"

мне надо ECC с регистром память тогда смогу поставить 96 ГБ? Как понять какая память у меня? Раз материнка поддерживает только ECC, осталось понять это REG или нет? И как найти ОЗУ ECC REG ? В большенстве магазинов нет такой характеристики в подборе(в фильтрах) , может не там ищу...

Comment: Надо полагать, что большинство магазинов уже не торгуют древней ddr3, смотрите на глобальных площадках и б.у

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Да, (по документации)
2. Сделать поиск по маркировке на модуле (M393B2G70BH0-CH9, например)
3. Материнка поддерживает REG (по документации)
4. Найти поддерживаемую память на сайте производителя: [Memory List](https://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/memory/display.cfm?sz=16&mspd=1.333&mtyp=33&id=144D7111B7126A9A938F3113403B15D6&prid=81240&type=DDR3&ecc=1&reg=1&fbd=0)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...и купить у поставщиков.